# Function which overrides bash command

Tags: bash

Is it possible to call a bash command which has been overridden with a function? I'd like to make `pushd` with no arguments alias to `pushd .` otherwise get normal behaviour.

I've tried

```
pushd(){
   if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
      pushd .
   else
      pushd $@
   fi
}
```

but this seems to give infinite recursion. Normally I'd use the full path to whatever program I'm overriding, but `push` is a built-in bash thing, so that's not possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use the `builtin` command:

```
pushd(){
   if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
      builtin pushd .
   else
      builtin pushd "$@"
   fi
}
```

Comment: The entire function could even be rewritten as `pushd() { builtin pushd "${1:-.}"; }`

Comment: ``"${@-.}"`` would be better, since `pushd` can take multiple arguments.